# How to animate an image as it grows from the width of a container to the full viewport width?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a container div with an image inside of it. When a user clicks the image, I want it to grow to fill the viewport width. This works for me, but I want it to animate smoothly as it grows, which does not.

How can I make the image grow smoothly from the centre of the page, rather than growing *in situ* until it touches the right edge of the viewport, and then jumping to the left and continuing until it fills the viewport?

---

Here's an example
(you can try it on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGLKJb)):

*HTML:*

```
<div>
  <img id="expandableImage" src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/200">
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.fullsize {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: zoom-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}
.smallsize {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: zoom-out;
}

@keyframes zoom-in {
  to {
    width: 100vw;
      position: relative;
      left: calc(-50vw + 50%);  
  }
}

@keyframes zoom-out {
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
  from {
    width: 100vw;
      position: relative;
      left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  }
}
```

*JS:*

```
document.getElementById( "expandableImage" ).addEventListener( "click", zoom );

function zoom() {
        if (this.className.indexOf("fullsize") > -1) {
            this.className = this.className.replace(" fullsize", "");
            this.className = this.className + " smallsize";
        } else {
            this.className = this.className.replace(" smallsize", "");
            this.className = this.className + " fullsize";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the animation just not work? If so, it could be that you need to prefix it to get it working in your browser. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) for full details on browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `@keyframes` for that, only with `transition` is enough.

http://jsfiddle.net/xnmojeyn/

```js
document.getElementById("expandableImage").addEventListener("click", zoom);

function zoom() {
    if (this.className.indexOf("fullsize") > -1) {
        this.className = this.className.replace(" fullsize", "");
        this.className = this.className + " smallsize";
    } else {
        this.className = this.className.replace(" smallsize", "");
        this.className = this.className + " fullsize";
    }
}
```

```css
body, p {
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fullsize {
    transition: all 1s;
    margin-left: -25vw;
    width: 100vw;
}
.smallsize {
    transition: all 1s;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>asdf</p>
    <img id="expandableImage" src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/200" />
    <p>Why it doesn't work</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! You even managed to answer before I noticed that the link I had posted was out-of-date.

For future viewers: [this link shows the solution and more closely resembles the code I posted in my question.](https://jsfiddle.net/b6p80r1o/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGLKwB

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue with `calc`

```
@keyframes zoom-in {
  to {
    width: 100vw;
      position: relative;
      left: calc(-50% + 50%);  
  }
}

@keyframes zoom-out {
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
  from {
    width: 100vw;
      position: relative;
      left: calc(-50% + 50%);
  }
```

}

http://jsbin.com/paxuketigu/2/

another example with float:left

http://jsbin.com/paxuketigu/3/

Comment: Did you mean to post two answers? Might want to delete the other one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30536948/1157054

Comment: Also, did you mean for this to be an answer? It seems more like a clarification of the OP's question...